# PHP error for login session

Tags: php

I have an error in a single line of code but I can't seem to find it. I've tried changing the quotes to all match but that doesn't do anything.  Please help.  here is where the error is

```
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i',",$_SESSION["id"]);
```

Comment: What's error message you get?

Comment: You have erroneous characters in there. Why the extra quote and/or comma?

Comment: preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i',$_SESSION["id"])   ?

Comment: -1 TYPO: $_SESSION is a variable not a string (a never ending one, BTW)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["id"]);
```

btw i dont know what you are trying to do i just solved your syntax error ;)

Comment: you are welcom , you can accept the answer if want ;)